# Stirng[] cannot be converted to string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I can't fix my error. I want a program that sends emails to multiple people. This is my code so far...

```
public static void sendEmailWithAttachments(String host, String port,
            final String userName, final String password, String[] toAddress,
            String subject, String message, String[] attachFiles)
            throws AddressException, MessagingException {
        // sets SMTP server properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.user", userName);
        properties.put("mail.password", password);

        // creates a new session with an authenticator
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
            }
        };
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

        // creates a new e-mail message
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
        InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
```

The `toAddress` in the `{new Internet Address(toAddress)}` is the part where it says String[] can't be converted to String.

```
InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
```

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: You would be better to make `toAddress` a String and call the method multiple times, once for each address. As it stands, your method does too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InternetAddress's constructor take a String as it's parameter and not String array. So you should try this below:

```
  InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress[0]) };
```

Comment: And what about `toAddress[1]`, `toAddress[2]`, etc.?  OP _did_ say "multiple people"...

Comment: yeah what about the toAddress[1], toAddress[2], etc? i followed your the code but it only sent 1 email not to multiple emails

Comment: you should iterate your toAddress to send all email

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over toAddress, wrap each string in an InternetAddress, and put it in toAddresses

```
InternetAddress[] toAddresses = new InternetAddress[toAddress.length];

for(int i = 0; i < toAddresses; i++) {
   toAddresses[i] = new InternetAddress(toAddress[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the array of internet addresses first, and then assigning a value:

```
InternetAddress[] toAddresses = new InternetAddress[1];
toAddresses[0] = new InternetAddress(toAddress);
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
```

Comment: 'InternetAddress[] toAddresses = new InternetAddress[1];'
'toAddresses = new InternetAddress("test@gmail.com");'

Comment: No, like this: `toAddresses[0] = new InternetAddress("test@gmail.com");`

Answer (score 0):

The error message pretty much says it all.  You tried to pass `toAddress`, an array of `String`, to a constructor of `InternetAddress`, and the only one-arg constructor of `InternetAddress` accepts a `String`, not a `String[]`.

You know that you need to turn your array of `String` into and array of `InternetAddress`, and obviously you were hoping that `new InternetAddress` might somehow do that.  But, sadly, that's just not how things work.  You'll have to convert your `String`s one at a time in a loop, like this:

```
InternetAddress[] toAddresses = new InternetAddress[toAddress.length];
for (int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; ++i)
{
    toAddresses[i] = new InternetAddress(toAddress[i]);
}
```

Comment: i did it but the part of <code> msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses); */ says confusing indention

Comment: Maybe your source analyzer prefers curly braces around for-loop bodies; I've altered my code example.